# how can I work with mysql 5.1 in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.10, mysql-5.1

When I run mysql 5.1 files with my ubuntu 12.10, it reports syntax error. it seems because the version 5.5 and version 5.1 is not fully compatible.

Since the 1GB .sql file is not written by me, I do not know how to change it for version 5.5.

The only solution seems to be that I should change 5.5 back to 5.1. However, when I download 5.1 mysql workbench and compile, it reports lack of dependencies. When I try to install mysql with command line, it reports package is not available.

I found that mysql 5.5 is pre-installed for ubuntu 12.10, I do not know if I should uninstall that first and I do not know how to uninstall that.

I hope I can find some help here since I do not find any good solution thorough the internet.

Sorry for my English, I am still working on it.

Comment: What does that syntax error say?

Comment: MySQL syntax didn't change all that much between 5.1 and 5.5. Do you know that the `.sql` file works in 5.1? I'd suspect it won't work in either and that you have just a simple syntax glitch.

Comment: It does not tell me what the syntax error is. This is all I got from mysql workbench: "ERROR: Line 7: SQL syntax error near '07-05-13.sql'. Statement skipped."

Comment: Can you do `mysql -uuser -p -v -v -v < nameofyourfile.sql` and post any error messages that you've got? *Obviously change user to user name you use to connect to your db*